# word boundary without case sensitivity

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match some word trying to ignoring the case sensitivity

For example

`\b(Yes|No)`

I need the my regex to find if the user enters `Yes` Or `YES` without case sensitivity

i tried to add `.*` which i know will not work `\b(Jan|Feb).*`

[regex test](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/MToZMV/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please check this one https://regex101.com/r/BdqRD1/2 it only works  writing `Feb` only

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/BdqRD1/3, works with everything

Comment: Thanks alot ....

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew pls as to the year i need it to takes "4 numbers" like "2020" but as to this regex it can takes 3 numbers only

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please update the question.

Comment: i changed `(9|20)` to `(19|20)` i think it works now  ( i need to match the years like 2020,1980) the years from 1900 +

Comment: Year regex - `(?<!\d)(?:19|20)\d{2}(?!\d)` or  `\b(?:19|20)\d{2}\b`